# How to get rid of DIGI passport certificate prompt

Tags: https, terminal-server, certificate

Currently, I am giving users access to DIGI passport port through HTTPS.

The problem is, user will be prompted some kind of certificate prompt. How do I get rid of that problem, so that users can straight away access the port through HTTPS without having to click on the prompt? (in details please)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely using a self-signed certificate. Clients can't verify the authenticity of self-signed certs, so they throw up the dialogue that you're seeing. To get rid of that, you'll either need to import your root CA certificate into all of your clients' browsers or perhaps more preferably, just purchase a certificate whose root CA is already included in most browsers.